# warning: 'void operator delete(void*, std::size_t)' called on unallocated object

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, placement-new

I am just playing with the placement-new operator. below code compiles and runs without any error on gcc version 11.2.But I am getting one warning as,

warning: 'void operator delete(void*, std::size_t)' called on unallocated object 'buf' [-Wfree-nonheap-object]x86-64 gcc 11.2 #1

Please see the code which I tried,

```
#include<iostream>
class sample
{
    public:
    sample()
    {
        std::cout<<"entered constructor"<<std::endl;
    }

    ~sample()
    {
        std::cout<<"entered destructor"<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    unsigned char buf[4];
    sample* k = new(buf) sample; 
    delete k;
    return 0;
}
```

Output as follows(I am using compiler explorer for the same)

Program returned: 139

Program stdout

entered constructor

entered destructor

Program stderr

free(): invalid pointer

Comment: You used placement `new` so you need to manually call the destructor (as `k->~sample();`) instead of using operator `delete`

Comment: You can't use `delete` with placement new.

Comment: @jr you did not allocate memory, so you do not have to free any memory. The storage `buf` will follow usual lifetime rules; as it has automatic storage, it will be disposed of at the end of its scope.  *(note: this complements UnholySheep's comment)*

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick responses and it helps/make me understand the mistake

Comment: `delete k;` is essentially the same as `delete buf;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `delete` on anything other than pointer returned by an **allocating** new expression results in undefined beheaviour.

*Placement*-new doesn't allocate anything. You may not `delete` a pointer returned by placement new. In order to destroy an object created using placement new, you must call the destructor explicitly, or you can use `std::destroy_at`:

```
sample* k = new(buf) sample; 
std::destroy_at(k);
// or
// k->~sample();
```